# PHP/HTML - Configuring the printing format of number of diamonds by row/s and column/s

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops, echo

I'm currently fixing the output format of, it should be like this:

[image]

The number of rings will be defined by input *row* and *column*. I used an array for storing each line of the output and loops to print the array that contains the output (Diamond) and to repeat its print by row and column.

Here's my current code (snippet):

```
    $arr[1] = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;**&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    $arr[2] = "&nbsp;*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;*&nbsp;";
    $arr[3] = "*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;*";
    $arr[4] = "*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;*";
    $arr[5] = "&nbsp;*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;*&nbsp;";
    $arr[6] = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;**&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

    for($Row_Itr = 1; $Row_Itr <= 6; $Row_Itr++){
       echo "<br>";
        for($repeat_column = 1; $repeat_column <= 2; $repeat_column++){
            for($repeat_row = 1; $repeat_row <= 1; $repeat_row++){
                echo $arr[$Row_Itr];

            }
        }
    }
```

And here's my current output:

**Row: 2, Column: 2**

[image]

> What could be the problem on my source code? and how to fix it in
>   order to achieve my goal output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather make your array start at index 0, and then loop over the number of rows, then the number of lines each diamond has, and then over the number of columns. After the innermost column loop, you output the line break:

```
$arr[0] = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;**&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
$arr[1] = "&nbsp;*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;*&nbsp;";
$arr[2] = "*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;*";
$arr[3] = "*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;*";
$arr[4] = "&nbsp;*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;*&nbsp;";
$arr[5] = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;**&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

$rows = 2;
$cols = 2;
$lines = count($arr);

for($r=0; $r<$rows; ++$r) {
  for($l=0; $l<$lines; ++$l) {
    for($c=0; $c<$cols; ++$c) {
      echo $arr[$l];
    }
    echo '<br>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function draw_diamonds($rows, $cols)
{
    $d = [
        '   **   ',
        ' *    * ',
        '*      *',
        '*      *',
        ' *    * ',
        '   **   ',
    ];

    for($i=0; $i<$rows; $i++)
        for($j=0; $j<6; $j++)
            echo str_repeat($d[$j], $cols), "\n";
}

draw_diamonds(1,2);
```

Output:

```
   **      **   
 *    *  *    * 
*      **      *
*      **      *
 *    *  *    * 
   **      **
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the row loop to be the first loop

```
<?php
    $arr[1] = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;**&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    $arr[2] = "&nbsp;*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;*&nbsp;";
    $arr[3] = "*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;*";
    $arr[4] = "*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;*";
    $arr[5] = "&nbsp;*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;*&nbsp;";
    $arr[6] = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;**&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    $rowcount = 3;$columncount = 2;
    for($repeat_row = 1; $repeat_row <= $rowcount; $repeat_row++){
        for($Row_Itr = 1; $Row_Itr <= 6; $Row_Itr++){
           echo "<br>";
            for($repeat_column = 1; $repeat_column <= $columncount; $repeat_column++){
                    echo $arr[$Row_Itr];
            }
        }
    }
?>
```